# Проверка графа на цикл

Tags: c++, алгоритм, графы

Дан ориентированный граф, нужно проверить есть ли в нем цикл. Вершин до 10^5, поэтому дфс с рекурсией не зайдет. спасибо

Comment: Чем БФС не нравится? И почему не зайдёт рекурсия, разрешите поинтересоваться?

Answer (score 2):

Поиск в глубину возможен и без рекурсии!

```
void DFS()
{
    stack<int> s;
    s.push(start);
    while (!s.empty())
    {
        int v = s.top();
        s.pop();
        for (int i = 0; i < edges[v].size(); ++i)
        {
            if (mark[edges[v][i]] == 0)
            {
                s.push(edges[v][i]);
                mark[edges[v][i]] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а какое условие на наличие цикла?

Comment: @RomanAlexandrovich прямо из [e-maxx](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/finding_cycle) цитирую: Произведём серию поисков в глубину в графе. Т.е. из каждой вершины, в которую мы ещё ни разу не приходили, запустим поиск в глубину, который при входе в вершину будет красить её в серый цвет, а при выходе - в чёрный. И если поиск в глубину пытается пойти в серую вершину, то это означает, что мы нашли цикл (если граф неориентированный, то случаи, когда поиск в глубину из какой-то вершины пытается пойти в предка, не считаются).

Comment: ну окей, а как это реализовать в вашем коде.

Comment: @RomanAlexandrovich Общий алгоритм я описал. Я уверен, вы умеете программировать и вам не составит труда перевести описание в код.

Comment: ну все равно спасибо)